# Want to refresh my label in c# windows form when windows services start and stop. am beginner to the c#

Tags: c#, windows, forms, service

Here is my code, When my service is stopped but my label is not updating, am beginner to the c#. want to make one application for the windows services.

```cs
namespace Services
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent()
            ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("TeamViewer");

            if (
                (sc.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)) 
                || (sc.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.StopPending))
            )
            { 
                label2.Text= "Stopped";
                label2.ForeColor = Color.Red; 
            }
            else
            {
                label2.Text = "Running";
                label2.ForeColor = Color.Green;
            }
            sc.Refresh();
```

Comment: Hi Welcome to stackoverflow, Did you debugger your `if else` condition? If you debug and check what value is stored in `sc.Status` when your service is stopped you will get to know your problem. I guess you are not changing status value when you are stopping your service.

Comment: Your code is written in the Form constructor. Thus, it is executed only once when your Form is created. You can check how to use the ```Timer``` class to execute this code every n seconds

Comment: There is [WaitForStatus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.waitforstatus) method which you could execute in background thread (to easily abort it in case software exit).